# dojo splitter not resizing properly with dynamic content

Tags: dojo, splitter

I'm creating a seemingly simple dojo 1.8 web page which contains an app layout div containing a tab container and an alarm panel below the tab container. They are separated by a splitter so the user can select how much of the alarms or the tabcontainer they want to see.

Here's the example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfW7u/

For the purpose of the demo, there's a timer which grows the table in the alarm panel by an entry every 2 seconds.

The problem(s):

1. If one doesn't do anything and just lets the table grow, no scroll bar appears in the alarm panel.
2. If one moves the splitter without having resized the browser window first, the splitter handle ends up in a weird location.
3. Resizing the browser window makes it behave like I would expect it to begin with.

Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm setting things up and that's causing this problem?
2. How can I catch the splitter has been moved event (name?)
3. How do I resize the splitter pane to an arbitrary height? I've tried using domStyle.set("alarmPanel", "height", 300) and this indeed sets the height property... but the pane does not resize!

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Partial solution: By triggering a resize event on the enclosing div (called "appLayout") it will do as asked. Check out the solution: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bfW7u/2/). But how to limit the splitter to a certain height when all the following calls return an empty string? `var ap = registry.byId("appLayout");`
`console.log(ap.domNode.style.height);`

`console.log(registry.byId("appLayout").get("style"));`
even the completely trivial dom call returns an empty string:

`console.log(dom.byId("appLayout").style.height);`

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forked your jsFiddle and made some modifications to it: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/f7qL6/

1. Get rid of `overflow: hidden` in `html, body` and explicitly set height of `alarmPanel`:

   ```
   .claro .demoLayout .edgePanel {
       height: 150px;
   }
   ```
2. This tricky one. You have two options: to listen to splitter's *drag and drop* or to listen to `ContentPane.resize` method invocation. Both via [`dojo/aspect`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect):

   ```
   // Drag and Drop
   var splitter = registry.byId("appLayout").getSplitter("bottom");
   var moveHandle = null;

   aspect.after(splitter, "_startDrag", function() {
       moveHandle = aspect.after(splitter.domNode, "onmousemove", function() {
           var coords = {
               x: !splitter.horizontal ? splitter.domNode.style.left : 0,
               y: splitter.horizontal ? splitter.domNode.style.top : 0
           }
           dom.byId("dndOutput").textContent = JSON.stringify(coords);
       })
   });  

   aspect.after(splitter, "_stopDrag", function() {
       moveHandle && moveHandle.remove();
   });


   // ContentPane.resize()   
   aspect.after(registry.byId("alarmPanel"), "resize", function(duno, size) {
       dom.byId("resizeOutput").textContent = JSON.stringify(size);
   });
   ```
3. Call `layout()` method after changing the size:

   ```
   registry.byId("alarmPanel").domNode.style.height = "200px";                
   registry.byId("appLayout").layout();
   ```

Comment: Fantastic comments. Concise, precise, and they work. Many thanks to you!